# R cut, break and quantiles with 'open' borders

Tags: r, data.table

I need to calculate breakpoints based on a certain subset of my data and apply it to my entire set. so eg, the 3rd and 7th decile of this subset should be my breakpoints.

what I basically want is a quantile function with 'open' boundaries left and right. eg

```
  quantile(0:10, probs= c(0, 0.3, 0.7, 1))
  0%  30%  70% 100% 
   0    3    7   10
```

but I only want to use the breakpoints 3 and 7 in my cut function which groups my vectors then.

I realize now that my question was not well thought out. to make it more clear: our subset vector was 0:10 and not we have the breakpoints (3 and 7), but I want to apply these breakpoints on a bigger vector, eg

```
    c(-5:12)
 [1] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

my aim is to cut this vector in such a way that everything below 3 (the third decile of my original vector) is in one group. everything between 3 and 7 is in the second group and everything above 7 is in one group. so overall three groups based on the cutpoints defined by the other vector.

could someone help me out with?
kind regards

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by open boundaries? What should happen to low and high scores (below 0.3, and above 0.7)?

I would think you have two options, see examples below. In the first the low and high scorers get assigned a value. In the second the -Inf and Inf get removed from the cut points and the low and high scorers get assigned NA.

If this doesn't answer your question, please could you add more detail, regarding what outcome you want to see?

```
# Determine cutpoints
cutPoints <- quantile(0:10, probs= c(0, 0.3, 0.7, 1))

# Option 1 - Low and highs get assigned a value
cut(0:10, breaks = cutPoints, labels = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE)

# Option 2 - Low and highs get assigned NA
cutPoints <- cutPoints[2:(length(cutPoints)-1)] # Remove -Inf and Inf
cut(0:10, breaks = cutPoints, labels = FALSE, include.lowest = TRUE)
```

Comment: sorry, I just realized my question was not well thought out and not clear what I want to do. I will edit my question

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing doesn't sound like open boundaries so much as just applying the cutpoints from one dataset to another. Why not just use the values themselves?

```
v1 <- c(0:10)
v2 <- c(-5:12)

q1 <- quantile(v1, probs = c(0, 0.3, 0.7, 1))
q2 <- quantile(v2, probs = c(0, which(v2 == q1[2])/length(v2)
   , which(v2 == q1[3])/length(v2), 1), type=3)

q2
       0%       50% 72.22222%      100% 
       -5         3         7        12
```